# How to store and retrieve an object of singleton class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Given a singleton class

```
    object singleton{
    ...
    }
```

I'm using a singleton to store a few values related to an object.I'm trying to store and retrieve it using SharedPreferences so that the next time the app is opened I can use that data.I also need to use this object(once retrieved) across all activities.However when I do

```
    val x = singleton
```

I can store the object, but am not able to access properties directly as

```
    singleton.propertyName
```

Hence I was asking is there any other way to store and retrieve which is better than using SharedPreferences
If I were to use

```
    x.propertyName
```

then isn't the simple way of accessing using just

```
    singleton.propertyName
```

lost?

Also is there any other way to store this object, if SharedPreferences is not the way to go?

Comment: Just by writing this you have already stored it in RAM. By writing `val x = singleton` you have retrieved it. What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Specified the need in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link, [Singletons with argument -Medium](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/kotlin-singletons-with-argument-194ef06edd9e)

to finish off your code,
Please type: `val r = singleton`
Then your object is retrieved.

Comment: 'When the concrete implementation of the singleton is generated by an external tool or library (Retrofit, Room, …) and its instance is retrieved using a custom builder or factory method, you usually declare the singleton as an interface or abstract class and it can’t be an object'. Got this from the link!!!                                                                                                                        Thanks!!!

Comment: @user10740241 No Problem!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write `x = singleton`, I wrote that in my comment just as a way to ask you what your actual need is.

You should definitely use `SharedPreferences` for persistent storage, but you can also keep the simple `singleton.propertyName` syntax. You just have to implement custom getters. Here are some snippets that I use:

```
val Context.sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences get() =
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)

val SharedPreferences.lastReloadedTimestamp: Long get() =
    getLong(KEY_LAST_RELOADED_TIMESTAMP, 0L)

fun SharedPreferences.Editor.setLastReloadedTimestamp(value: Long): SharedPreferences.Editor =
    putLong(KEY_LAST_RELOADED_TIMESTAMP, value)

inline fun SharedPreferences.applyUpdate(block: SharedPreferences.Editor.() -> Unit) {
    with (edit()) {
        try {
            block()
        } finally {
            apply()
        }
    }
}
```

I don't use a singleton object, but implement everything as an extension function on `Context`. I find this a safer way than loading the prefs into RAM once and then missing possible updates during the app's lifetime.

Notice that, to set properties, I don't use a custom setter, but rather an extension function on `Editor`. This allows me to group several updates in the same transaction on shared prefs:

```
context.sharedPrefs.applyUpdate {
    setLastReloadedTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
    setLocationLat(location.lat)
    setLocationLon(location.lon)
}
```